# Open a .txt file on Android

Tags: c#, android, file, unity-game-engine

I am currently working in Unity3D and wish to simply open a .txt file upon clicking on a button.

EDIT : When I say open a .txt file, I mean open it in some editor on the device, not open it asnd save it's content to some string in my app. Kind of like opening a browser to access a website from the app.

Here's the code I currently have (C#) :

```
private void ShowTextFile(string fileName)
{
    Application.OpenURL(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/PATH/" + fileName);
}
```

But it's not working ! What am I missing ?

EDIT : I'm expecting for the .txt file to open in another window (like opening a web browser, for example), but it simply isn't doing anything. Not even getting an error.

EDIT2 : I tried using Application.persistentDataPath instead, and in both cases, it says my .txt file doesn't exist. However, when using Application.persistentDataPath, it opens up a message box asking me what I want to open the file with. Whatever I choose, it will give me an error, telling me error loading file or something like that. I've also noticed that it opens "file:///". Is it normal that there is a file:/// before the path ?

EDIT3 (I'm on fire !) : I think the problem might be related to the fact that there is a "." in my path (the com.me.myapp in the data path). Is there any way to avoid this ? Am I even looking at the right path ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works ! Here's the thing, the streaming assets path, on Android, returns a path that can only be read by a WWW object. So I simply read it with a WWW object then recreated the file in my persistent data path. Added a check to make sure the file doesn't already exist before creating it. Also, make sure you create the directory in case it doesn't exist, else you'll get an error. Note that this solution is probably not optimal if you have large files that are regularly accessed.

```
    string realPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/PATH/" + fileName;

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(realPath))
    {
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/PATH/"))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/PATH/");
        }

        WWW reader = new WWW(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/PATH/" + realPath);
        while ( ! reader.isDone) {}

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(realPath, reader.bytes);
    }

    Application.OpenURL(realPath);
```

If anyone has anything to add to this answer, feel free !

Comment: will accept my answer in 4 hours (I can't do it now for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried opening a txt file on Android before, using this:

```
TextAsset txt = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("file", typeof(TextAsset));
string content = txt.text;
```

Where `file` is the name of the txt file (don't need to write `file.txt`).
The variable string will contain the contents of the text file, you just need to loop through them afterwards.

This method requires:

```
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
```

Put `file.txt` inside a directory named "Resources" (inside Assets dir), if it isn't there then create a new one.

Comment: I'm looking to open the file in some editor, not save it's text in a string variable and then read it !

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for Android:

```
    var rpath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "file_name");

    WWW www = new WWW(rpath);
    yield return www;
    StringReader streamReader = new StringReader(www.text);
    text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

For iOS:

```
    var rpath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "file_name");
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(rpath);
    text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Note: file_name in StreamingAssets folder

Comment: I'm looking to open the file in some editor, not save it's text in a string variable and then read it ! (See top edit in question)